# How to load script with jquery.load()?

Tags: jquery, url, load, selector

I have a question.

In my file content.html I have script. 
When load this with the `load()` function of jQuery, the page shows but the script doesn't work. I think it's because of a selector.

How can I solve that ?

**EDIT :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#content').load('content.html #toLoad', function(){});
})
```

Thanks

Comment: you will need to work on the question it is not very clear

Comment: Don't pass an empty second argument to `.load()`. What's that supposed to accomplish? Does the page at `content.html` contain an element with ID `toLoad`?

Comment: Or do it with just javascript ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521482/281965

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say "the script doesn't work" do you mean there's javascript in the page you're loading through ajax?

It's not going to work, ever, at least not directly.

You have two choices. Parse out the script from the content you've loaded, and use `eval` to run it.

A better way is to use [`$.getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load (and execute) javascript. If you want to bind your javascript with the HTML you've loaded, then you need some convention to identify the script. For example you could include a tag in your dynamically loaded html:

`<span style="display:none;" id="script">/scripts/somescript.js</span>`

Then look for a span with id="script" when you load the content, if you find it, use `$.getScript` to load the script it identifies.

example...

```
$.load('content.html #toLoad', function(data){
    var $script = $(data).find('span[id=script]');
    if ($script.length) {
        $.getScript($script.html());
        // remove the span tag -- no need to render it
        $script.remove();
    }
    $('#content').html(data);
});
```

Comment: How can i use $.getScript with id="script" ?

Comment: Why did you do `$.getScript($script.html());` ? And what I have to do if my script is inline (inside `content.html`)? Not a external file `blabla.js`

Comment: `$script.html()` is the inner HTML of the span tag, e.g. `/scripts/somescript.js`. `$.getScript` loads it from that path. If the script is inline, then you need to extract it and use `eval' to execute it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question from several years ago, but I was not satisfied with the accepted answer when I stumbled onto this page. Here's an alternative I wrote that automatically finds all of the scripts within the content you are loading, and runs each of those scripts regardless of whether the script is inline or an external file.

```
$("#content").load("content.html #toLoad", function(data) {
    var scripts = $(data).find("script");

    if (scripts.length) {
        $(scripts).each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("src")) {
                $.getScript($(this).attr("src"));
            }
            else {
                eval($(this).html());
            }
        });
    }

});
```

This code finds all of the script elements in the content that is being loaded, and loops through each of these elements. If the element has a `src` attribute, meaning it is a script from an external file, we use the `jQuery.getScript` method of fetching and running the script. If the element does not have a `src` attribute, meaning it is an inline script, we simply use `eval` to run the code.

I've tested this method in Chrome and it works. Remember to be cautious when using `eval`, as it can run potentially unsafe scripts and is generally considered harmful. You might want to avoid using inline scripts when using this method in order to avoid having to use `eval`.