# Dynamically load JS inside JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic web page where  I need to import an external JS file (under an `IF` condition) inside another javascript file.

I tried to search for a feasible solution but it didn't work.

I have tried loading a JS file to the DOM using `document.createElement()` but it also didn't work. Apparently the Js was loaded into the DOM but was not accessible in the current JS file.

Solution in jQuery will also be fine

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by doing this (so that an alternative may be suggested)?

Comment: I am creating a dynamic page. That displays some effects conditionally. But the external JS can't be permanently included in the HTML

Comment: See also: http://www.jspatterns.com/the-ridiculous-case-of-adding-a-script-element/

Answer (score 179, accepted):

jQuery's `$.getScript()` is buggy sometimes, so I use my own implementation of it like:

```
jQuery.loadScript = function (url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: callback,
        async: true
    });
}
```

and use it like:

```
if (typeof someObject == 'undefined') $.loadScript('url_to_someScript.js', function(){
    //Stuff to do after someScript has loaded
});
```

Comment: I tweaked your script just a little made it execute if loaded otherwise load then execute...
    jQuery.pluginSafe = function (name, url, callback) {
     if(jQuery[name]){
      callback;
     } else {
      jQuery.ajax({...});
     }
    }

Comment: can you provide some info on when it's buggy?

Comment: It's not ideal because the file loaded in such isn't shown in Sources in DevTools. It's because this file is `eval`ed

Comment: An additional problem is that this would swallow any syntax errors. So you'd want to catch them in `fail()`.

Answer (score 925):

My guess is that in your DOM-only solution you did something like:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = something;
//do stuff with the script
```

First of all, that won't work because the script is not added to the document tree, so it won't be loaded. Furthermore, even when you do, execution of javascript continues while the other script is loading, so its content will not be available to you until that script is fully loaded.

You can listen to the script's `load` event, and do things with the results as you would. So:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
    //do stuff with the script
};
script.src = something;

document.head.appendChild(script); //or something of the likes
```

Comment: No point in over complicating things. Bravo

Comment: make sure to set the `src` attribute after the `onload` attribute [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16231055/1852456)

Comment: This really should be the best answer, no need to use a jQuery for simple tasks like this!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, onload is called before the script is loaded and run - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16806243/2203164)

Comment: Worked for me also :)

Comment: @woojoo666 why after `onload`?  Isn't setting the `src` only before the `appendchild` enough?

Comment: @AliSharabiani oops you're right, it only matters if the element is already on the page. From my experience it's more common to first have the element on the page before setting the `src`, mainly bc of all the cases where you want to *change* the `src` dynamically, like for `img` tags and such. So I think its better practice to just get used to putting `src` after `onload`

Comment: how to mark it as `async` and `defer`?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev: Don't mark dynamically loaded scripts with async/defer. 
 Since you're loading the script dynamically, the decision of when to load the script is already under your own control.

Comment: Instead of `script.[ATTR]`, it might be better to use `script.setAttribute('ATTR', 'VALUE')` as not all attributes seem to apply when you `appendChild()`. Example: 

This does not apply the `crossorigin` attribute when you call `appendChild()`:
`script.crossorigin = 'anonymous';`

But this does:
`script.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');`

Comment: In order to get jquery working after being loaded dynamically, I had to change the "appendChild" to "prepend" !!!

Comment: Mozilla documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts

Comment: Fixed link to Mozilla documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#dynamically_importing_scripts

Answer (score 130):

I need to do this frequently, so I use this:

```
var loadJS = function(url, implementationCode, location){
    //url is URL of external file, implementationCode is the code
    //to be called from the file, location is the location to 
    //insert the <script> element

    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.src = url;

    scriptTag.onload = implementationCode;
    scriptTag.onreadystatechange = implementationCode;

    location.appendChild(scriptTag);
};
var yourCodeToBeCalled = function(){
//your code goes here
}
loadJS('yourcode.js', yourCodeToBeCalled, document.body);
```

For more information, see this site [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file), which is the source of my function idea.

Comment: Upvoted for including `onload`.

Comment: This code is excellent.  Very little modifications were required to make it fully functional across chrome/firefox/opera.  I wrote my own markdown rewriter in 6 lines of html which loads the markdown script.  For content I add <template> tags with markdown.  The rewriter appends the result of transforming markdown to HTML.  Just plain beautiful.  Thank you.

Comment: A bit more work and I reduced ALL the html to 3 lines.  The <template> tags with content are transformed and appended.  Better than any of my prior efforts.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en"><head><meta   charset="utf-8" /></head><body>
    <nav></nav>
            <template class="markdown">
        == hello ==
            </template>
            <template id="Spanish" class="markdown">
        == hola ==
            </template>
        </body><script type="text/javascript"  src="/js/rewrite.js"></script>
    </html>

Answer (score 30):

You may dynamically load the js inside the page not another js file.

You have to use the [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load the js file.

```
$.getScript("ajax/test.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  console.log(data); // data returned
  console.log(textStatus); // success
  console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
  console.log('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution that readily works. It also works well nested inside other functions. Highly recommend this option.

Comment: I don't like that is uses jQuery. I need to do this in plain old JS

Answer (score 20):

Necromancing.

I use this to load dependant scripts;
it works with IE8+ without adding any dependency on another  library like jQuery !

```
var cScriptLoader = (function ()
{
    function cScriptLoader(files)
    {
        var _this = this;
        this.log = function (t)
        {
            console.log("ScriptLoader: " + t);
        };
        this.withNoCache = function (filename)
        {
            if (filename.indexOf("?") === -1)
                filename += "?no_cache=" + new Date().getTime();
            else
                filename += "&no_cache=" + new Date().getTime();
            return filename;
        };
        this.loadStyle = function (filename)
        {
            // HTMLLinkElement
            var link = document.createElement("link");
            link.rel = "stylesheet";
            link.type = "text/css";
            link.href = _this.withNoCache(filename);
            _this.log('Loading style ' + filename);
            link.onload = function ()
            {
                _this.log('Loaded style "' + filename + '".');
            };
            link.onerror = function ()
            {
                _this.log('Error loading style "' + filename + '".');
            };
            _this.m_head.appendChild(link);
        };
        this.loadScript = function (i)
        {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = _this.withNoCache(_this.m_js_files[i]);
            var loadNextScript = function ()
            {
                if (i + 1 < _this.m_js_files.length)
                {
                    _this.loadScript(i + 1);
                }
            };
            script.onload = function ()
            {
                _this.log('Loaded script "' + _this.m_js_files[i] + '".');
                loadNextScript();
            };
            script.onerror = function ()
            {
                _this.log('Error loading script "' + _this.m_js_files[i] + '".');
                loadNextScript();
            };
            _this.log('Loading script "' + _this.m_js_files[i] + '".');
            _this.m_head.appendChild(script);
        };
        this.loadFiles = function ()
        {
            // this.log(this.m_css_files);
            // this.log(this.m_js_files);
            for (var i = 0; i < _this.m_css_files.length; ++i)
                _this.loadStyle(_this.m_css_files[i]);
            _this.loadScript(0);
        };
        this.m_js_files = [];
        this.m_css_files = [];
        this.m_head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        // this.m_head = document.head; // IE9+ only
        function endsWith(str, suffix)
        {
            if (str === null || suffix === null)
                return false;
            return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i)
        {
            if (endsWith(files[i], ".css"))
            {
                this.m_css_files.push(files[i]);
            }
            else if (endsWith(files[i], ".js"))
            {
                this.m_js_files.push(files[i]);
            }
            else
                this.log('Error unknown filetype "' + files[i] + '".');
        }
    }
    return cScriptLoader;
})();
var ScriptLoader = new cScriptLoader(["foo.css", "Scripts/Script4.js", "foobar.css", "Scripts/Script1.js", "Scripts/Script2.js", "Scripts/Script3.js"]);
ScriptLoader.loadFiles();
```

If you are interested in the [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)-version used to create this:

```
class cScriptLoader {
    private m_js_files: string[];
    private m_css_files: string[];
    private m_head:HTMLHeadElement;
    
    private log = (t:any) =>
    {
        console.log("ScriptLoader: " + t);
    }
    
    
    constructor(files: string[]) {
        this.m_js_files = [];
        this.m_css_files = [];
        this.m_head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        // this.m_head = document.head; // IE9+ only
        
        
        function endsWith(str:string, suffix:string):boolean 
        {
            if(str === null || suffix === null)
                return false;
                
            return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
        }
        
        
        for(let i:number = 0; i < files.length; ++i) 
        {
            if(endsWith(files[i], ".css"))
            {
                this.m_css_files.push(files[i]);
            }
            else if(endsWith(files[i], ".js"))
            {
                this.m_js_files.push(files[i]);
            }
            else
                this.log('Error unknown filetype "' + files[i] +'".');
        }
        
    }
    
    
    public withNoCache = (filename:string):string =>
    {
        if(filename.indexOf("?") === -1)
            filename += "?no_cache=" + new Date().getTime();
        else
            filename += "&no_cache=" + new Date().getTime();
            
        return filename;    
    }
    

    public loadStyle = (filename:string) =>
    {
        // HTMLLinkElement
        let link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.href = this.withNoCache(filename);
        
        this.log('Loading style ' + filename);
        link.onload = () =>
        {
            this.log('Loaded style "' + filename + '".');
            
        };
        
        link.onerror = () =>
        {
            this.log('Error loading style "' + filename + '".');
        };
        
        this.m_head.appendChild(link);
    }
    
    
    public loadScript = (i:number) => 
    {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = this.withNoCache(this.m_js_files[i]);
        
        var loadNextScript = () => 
        {
            if (i + 1 < this.m_js_files.length)
            {
                this.loadScript(i + 1);
            }
        }
        
        script.onload = () =>
        {
            this.log('Loaded script "' + this.m_js_files[i] + '".');
            loadNextScript();
        };
        
        
        script.onerror = () =>
        {
            this.log('Error loading script "' + this.m_js_files[i] + '".');
            loadNextScript();
        };
        
        
        this.log('Loading script "' + this.m_js_files[i] + '".');
        this.m_head.appendChild(script);
    }
    
    public loadFiles = () => 
    {
        // this.log(this.m_css_files);
        // this.log(this.m_js_files);
        
        for(let i:number = 0; i < this.m_css_files.length; ++i)
            this.loadStyle(this.m_css_files[i])
        
        this.loadScript(0);
    }
    
}


var ScriptLoader = new cScriptLoader(["foo.css", "Scripts/Script4.js", "foobar.css", "Scripts/Script1.js", "Scripts/Script2.js", "Scripts/Script3.js"]);
ScriptLoader.loadFiles();
```

If it's to load a dynamic list of scripts, write the scripts into an attribute, such as data-main, e.g.
`<script src="scriptloader.js" data-main="file1.js,file2.js,file3.js,etc." ></script>` 
and do a `element.getAttribute("data-main").split(',')`

such as

```
var target = document.currentScript || (function() {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  // Note: this is for IE as IE doesn't support currentScript
  // this does not work if you have deferred loading with async
  // e.g. <script src="..." async="async" ></script>
  // https://web.archive.org/web/20180618155601/https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_script_async.asp
  return scripts[scripts.length - 1];
})();

target.getAttribute("data-main").split(',')
```

to obtain the list.

Comment: Thank you, that's incredible. I think it worth adding callback option since we might want to execute functions based on these resources at the end of their loading.

Comment: Why are you using `var` in typescript code?

Comment: @canbax: Old version of TS didn't reject var - old habits die hard.

Answer (score 10):

The **`jQuery.getScript()`** method is a shorthand of the Ajax function (with the dataType attribute: `$.ajax({ url: url,`**`dataType: "script"`**`})`)

If you want the scripts to be cachable, either use [**RequireJS**](http://requirejs.org/) or follow jQuery's example on extending the `jQuery.getScript` method similar to the following.

```
jQuery.cachedScript = function( url, options ) {

  // Allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
  options = $.extend( options || {}, {
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    url: url
  });

  // Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
  // Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
  return jQuery.ajax( options );
};

// Usage
$.cachedScript( "ajax/test.js" ).done(function( script, textStatus ) {
  console.log( textStatus );
});
```

*Reference: [jQuery.getScript() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)*

Answer (score 6):

jQuery has [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

> **Description**: Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using JQuery:

```
$.getScript("ajax/test.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  console.log(data); //data returned
  console.log(textStatus); //success
  console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
  console.log('Load was performed.');
});
```

this link should help:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 5):

I'm recommend using requirejs with AMD javascript class files

good example of how to use it here

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/

Answer (score 5):

To author my plugin I needed to load external scripts and styles inside a JS file, all of which were predefined. To achieve this, I did the following:

```
    this.loadRequiredFiles = function (callback) {
        var scripts = ['xx.js', 'yy.js'];
        var styles = ['zz.css'];
        var filesloaded = 0;
        var filestoload = scripts.length + styles.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            log('Loading script ' + scripts[i]);
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = scripts[i];
            script.onload = function () {
                log('Loaded script');
                log(this);
                filesloaded++;  // (This means increment, i.e. add one)
                finishLoad();
            };
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
            log('Loading style ' + styles[i]);
            var style = document.createElement('link');
            style.rel = 'stylesheet';
            style.href = styles[i];
            style.type = 'text/css';
            style.onload = function () {
                log('Loaded style');
                log(this);
                filesloaded++;
                finishLoad();
            };
            document.head.appendChild(style);
        }
        function finishLoad() {
            if (filesloaded === filestoload) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    };
```

More of the script in context:

```
function myPlugin() {

    var opts = {
        verbose: false
    };                          ///< The options required to run this function
    var self = this;            ///< An alias to 'this' in case we're in jQuery                         ///< Constants required for this function to work

    this.getOptions = function() {
        return opts;
    };

    this.setOptions = function(options) {
        for (var x in options) {
            opts[x] = options[x];
        }
    };

    /**
     * @brief Load the required files for this plugin
     * @param {Function} callback A callback function to run when all files have been loaded
     */
    this.loadRequiredFiles = function (callback) {
        var scripts = ['xx.js', 'yy.js'];
        var styles = ['zz.css'];
        var filesloaded = 0;
        var filestoload = scripts.length + styles.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            log('Loading script ' + scripts[i]);
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = scripts[i];
            script.onload = function () {
                log('Loaded script');
                log(this);
                filesloaded++;
                finishLoad();
            };
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
            log('Loading style ' + styles[i]);
            var style = document.createElement('link');
            style.rel = 'stylesheet';
            style.href = styles[i];
            style.type = 'text/css';
            style.onload = function () {
                log('Loaded style');
                log(this);
                filesloaded++;
                finishLoad();
            };
            document.head.appendChild(style);
        }
        function finishLoad() {
            if (filesloaded === filestoload) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * @brief Enable user-controlled logging within this function
     * @param {String} msg The message to log
     * @param {Boolean} force True to log message even if user has set logging to false
     */
    function log(msg, force) {
        if (opts.verbose || force) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief Initialise this function
     */
    this.init = function() {
        self.loadRequiredFiles(self.afterLoadRequiredFiles);
    };

    this.afterLoadRequiredFiles = function () {
        // Do stuff
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little lib to load javascript and CSS files dynamically:

https://github.com/todotresde/javascript-loader

I guess is usefull to load css and js files in order and dynamically.

Support to extend to load any lib you want, and not just the main file, you can use it to load custom files.

I.E.:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/javascript-loader.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            registerLib("threejs", test);

            function test(){
                console.log(THREE);
            }

            registerLib("tinymce", draw);

            function draw(){
                tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
            }

        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>Your content here.</textarea>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have **many files** with **dependencies**, use AMD/RequireJS.
http://requirejs.org/