# When does a dynamically loaded JavaScript library become available?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I wrote JavaScript library to use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) and its associated libraries. However, I don't want to always load FileSaver.js whenever someone wants to use my library. And I don't want to force them to load all the various FileSaver related JavaScript libraries with `script` tags themselves (or even load one of mine which would do that).

Instead, what I'd prefer is something like this. When they call my `createImage` function, it first does the following:

```
function createImage(image, name) {
  if (typeof(saveAs) !== 'function') {
    var element = document.createElement('script');
    element.async = false;
    element.src = 'FileSaver.js';
    element.type = 'text/javascript';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.body).appendChild(element);
  }
  // now do the saveImage code
}
```

Problem is, after the above, the `saveAs` function is still not defined. It's only **after** my `createImage` completes is the `saveAs` function finally defined.

Comment: use the script.onload event. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the Holistic solution is to use a module system. AMD is (in-my-just-an-observation-please-dont-start-a-holy-war-opinion) probably the most commonly used system for browser async code loading. AMD is just a spec, but something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) is a very popular tool for using AMD modules.

The idea being that you can define dependencies between your modules, and require.js will go fetch them if need be. The general idea is to mimic the import/namespace functionality of other languages (like java, C#, or python). "code sharing" i think is the term?

simply put you have all your code in a callback function that runs once the dependencies are loaded, so you can be sure the needed objects and methods are present.

**update 2015**

just an addendum.  while the info above is still correct, front end code management is moving quickly toward solutions like Webpack and Browserify, which bundle and concatenate code of any module type and both have dynamic code loading capabilities  (webpack calls this code splitting). That coupled with the exponential growth of npm for dependency management is beginning to make AMD less relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, what you need to do is listen for the script to finish loading. Unfortunately there are some bugs with this code for ie<7.

This is the way Mootools `Asset.javascript` loads scripts and calls a callback when its complete:

```
var loadScript = function (source, properties) {
    properties || (properties = {});
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = source;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    var doc = properties.document || document, load = properties.onload || properties.onLoad;
    return delete properties.onload, delete properties.onLoad, delete properties.document, 
    load && (script.addEventListener ? script.addEventListener("load", load) : script.attachEvent("readystatechange", function() {
        [ "loaded", "complete" ].indexOf(this.readyState) >= 0 && load.call(this);
    })), script.set(properties).appendChild(doc.head);
}
```

Now in `loadImage` you can load the file library as follows:

```
function createImage(image, name) {
  function createImg() {
      // now do the saveImage code
  }
  if (typeof(saveAs) !== 'function') {
     loadScript("FileSaver.js", {onLoad: createImg});//load library
  }
  else {
     createImg();
  }
}
```

Should work on most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use Head.js: http://headjs.com/

It will load scripts on demand.

Answer (score 0):

So I agree with the AMD comment (can't put code blocking into comments meh...)

Here's what I do for FileSaver.js

First in my requirejs config / main.js :

```
(function() {
    // REMEMBER TO DUPLICATE CHANGES IN GRUNTFILE.JS
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            "jquery": "PATH/jquery.min", // NO .js
            "lib.filesaver" : "PATH/FileSaver", // NO .js
            "shim.blob" : "PATH/Blob" // NO .js
        },
        shim: {
            "lib.filesaver": {deps: ["shim.blob"]}
        }
    });

    define([
        "jquery"
    ], function(
        $
        ) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // start up code...
            });
        return {};
        });
})();
```

Then I place the Blob.js/jquery and Filersaver in correct places

I also created a IEShim for pre IE10

```
define([], function () {
    /**
     * @class IEshims
     * container for static IE shim functions
     */
    var IEShims = {
        /**
         * saveFile, pops up a built in javascript file as a download
         * @param {String} filename, eg doc.csv
         * @param {String} filecontent eg "this","is","csv"
         */
        saveAs: function (filename, filecontent, mimetype ) {
            var w = window.open();
            var doc = w.document;
            doc.open( mimetype,'replace');
            doc.charset = "utf-8";
            doc.write(filecontent);
            doc.close();
            doc.execCommand("SaveAs", null, filename);
        }
    };
    return IEShims;
});
```

And lastly when I want to use Filesaver make it required (along with IEShim for bad browsers)

```
define([
"lib.filesaver",
"IEShims"
],
function (
    FileSaver, // it's empty, see saveAs global var
    IEShims
    ) {
...
    var fileName = "helloworld.txt";
    var fileContents = "Me haz file contents, K Thx Bye";
    var mimeType = "text/plain";
    if(saveAs) {
        var blob = new Blob(
            [fileContents],
            {type: mimeType + ";charset=" + document.characterSet}
        );
        saveAs(blob, fileName);
    } else {
        IEShims.saveAs(fileName, fileContents,mimeType );
    }
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to put your code in the `onload` handler of the `script` tag you create:

```html
<script>
  var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
      js = document.createElement('script');
  js.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Snowstorm/20131208/snowstorm-min.js';
  js.onload = function () {
    // do stuff with your dynamically loaded script
    snowStorm.snowColor = '#99ccff';
  };
  firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(js, firstScript);
</script>
```

Loading scripts dynamically this way is [done by Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/31282622#31282622).