# How to add javascript file dynamically in the head of html?

Tags: javascript, html

From below code I am trying to load javascript file  TestJScript.js dynamically and after loading want to call javascript function LoadData() exist in that file. But I am getting error please check image.

**Note: Error get only on IE-8.0.6001 update 0.**

Please suggest me correction such that It will work from 6 to all version of IE.
Or any another solution.

**if it require any windows updates. Please let me know.**

**Please don't suggest with JQUERY code**

Javascript file code :

```
function LoadData() {   
    alert('ok');
}
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
        <script>

            function LoadJSFile() {

                    var js = document.createElement("script")
                    js.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
                    js.setAttribute("src", "C:\\TestJScript.js")                    
                    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js)

                    //call below function exist in TestJScript.js file
                    LoadData();
                }              

        </script>
      </head>
<body onload="LoadJSFile();">

</body>
</html>
```

Error Image:[image]

Comment: Are you doing web dev using IE and windows XP? I'm shocked.

Comment: @prM Maybe it's a virtual machine and be was just testing...

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat true! oh, and xhtml, onload, src="C:\\..."..

Comment: I am making windows application which uses WebBrowser control. Hence I am depends on IE only. bcoz I will never touch client machines to install updates.

Comment: You could try loading the script as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14521482/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using c# code then another solution to solve this script error is, invoke script through c# code.
Code:

/

```
/Assiging html value to control
                webBrowser.DocumentText = "HTML content";               
//Calling document load completed event
                webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {                
            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = webBrowser.Document;
            HtmlElement htmlElementHead = htmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement HtmlElementScript = htmlDocument.CreateElement("script");
            HtmlElementScript.SetAttribute("text", "C:\\TestJScript.js");
            htmlElementHead.AppendChild(HtmlElementScript);
            htmlDocument.InvokeScript("LoadData");
            webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://dustindiaz.com/scriptjs.
Like this:

```
$script('yui-base.js', function() {
  // do stuff with base...
  $script(['yui-anim.js', 'yui-connect.js'], function() {
    // do stuff with anim and connect...
  });
  $script('yui-drag.js', function() {
    // do stuff with drag...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error reports a problem in the javascript file that you're loading. So the problem lies not in how you dynamically load the javascript file, but in the javascript file itself.

Comment: As I said, It is not working on IE-8 Only. I have added script file code also.

Comment: Have you tried putting <script src="file:///C:/TestJScript.sj"></script> directly in your html, to see if that gives errors?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with the file once it has loaded. Are you sure there is no syntax error in the file itself.

Also, I would recommend you use a relative path to the javascript file instead of the absolute path.

EDIT:

Try this:

```
function LoadJSFile() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "C:\\TestJScript.js";
  script.onload = function () {
    LoadData();
  };

   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script)     
}
```

Comment: Husman, It works on all IE version except IE-8. I have added script file code also.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<script>
function LoadJSFile(src, callback) {
    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.src = src;
    js.async = true;
    js.onreadystatechange = js.onload = function() {
        var state = js.readyState;
        if (!callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
            callback.done = true;
            callback();
        }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}
LoadJSFile('C:\\TestJScript.js', function() { 
    LoadData();
});
</script>
```