# How to make jQuery code not work for logged in Wordpress users?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this code in my header.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery("a")
    .filter(function() {
      var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
      // return true if href exists and matches the regular expression
      return href && href.match(/mywebsite\.com\/(page)\//);
    })
    .click(function(){ 
      jQuery("a").attr("target","_blank"); 
      url = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
      jQuery(this).attr('href','/te3/out.php?l=click&u=' + escape(url)); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

How can I make this code only work for users that are not logged in? (I'm using wordpress self-hosted)

Right now the code opens every '/page/*' in a new tab and makes it go through /te3/out.php but I would like that not to happen to logged in users.

I'm pretty new to this so please make it easy to understand.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Comment: Surely wordpress gives you a cookie if you are logged in.  If it does you can simply check if that cookie is present by looking at string: document.cookie - if it is there then don't load the script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put **condition** that if user is not logged in then use script else not.For that you can use [is_user_logged_in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in#Examples).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<?php 
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) :
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery("a")
        .filter(function() {
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        // return true if href exists and matches the regular expression
        return href && href.match(/mywebsite\.com\/(page)\//);
    })
    .click(function(){ 
        jQuery("a").attr("target","_blank"); 
        url = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
        jQuery(this).attr('href','/te3/out.php?l=click&u=' + escape(url)); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
<?php 
    endif;
?>
```