# How can I fire a function in a click(function)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript file which I want to start when a div has been clicked.

I have already this when clicking the div "option_one", an input will be set to "Option 1":

```
$("#option_one").click(function() {
$("#input").val('Option 1');    
});
```

How can I fire another js file after clicking the div?

I try something with getScript but I couldn't get it working.

Kind regards,

Arie

Comment: what do you mean with fire another js file?

Comment: I don't understand you want to load another js file on ´#option_one´ click?

Comment: just an javascript file, like calculating.js

Comment: if you include the file in the page on load, you will have access to the functions in that file so can just add them to your existing click event

Comment: @andybeli Yep, after clicking on the div option_one, I want to load the js file calculating.js in the .click(function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically load JS inside JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js)

Comment: Tnx for clearing this one out, I was making it to difficult ......... ;-) I wanted to load the file after clicking but loading the file at page load and calling the function was the solution for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to load the `calculate.js` file on the `click` event. Just load it with the page load like so:

HTML:

```
<!--Your page HTML here... -->

<!--Before your closing body tag-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calculate.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
// This is inside somefile.js
$("#option_one").click(function() {

    $("#input").val('Option 1');

    // This function is inside calculate.js
    calculate();    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#option_one").click(function() {
    $("#input").val('Option 1');

    $.getScript( "path/calculating.js" )
    .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
        //Just after the scripts finishes loading you will be able
        //to perform/use functionality included on this script
        console.log( textStatus );
    })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
        console.log("Triggered ajaxError handler.");
    });
});
```