# My Google Map display only if i refresh my page ? How to display it the first time?

Tags: symfony, google-maps, twig, environment-variables

I have integrated a Google Map on my Website. I have saved my token_api in a variable in .env and declare as global in twig.yaml. If i access the token via {{token_google_api}} my map display only if i refresh my page.

I have tried to paste my token in raw and it work well, but i don't want to have a secret token write in raw in my code.

**Display on refresh:**

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{token_google_api}}&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**Display well:**

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_token_in_raw&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**my .env**

```
TOKEN_GOOGLE_API=my_token_in_raw
```

**my twig.yaml**

```
twig:
    globals:
        token_google_api: '%env(TOKEN_GOOGLE_API)%'
```

Actually i have to refresh my page to display the map. I expect the map display when i come to the page the first time.

Edit: It seems to work properly on Edge. but not in Firefox & Chrome so, there is the css for my map div maybe should be helpful.

```css
#map {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is happening because you're using a variable in your script that loads the Maps API, but this is HTML. What you can do is load the script using JavaScript. There's a good example in related thread [dynamically set googleapi key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342359/dynamically-set-googleapi-key)

In any case, your API key is a browser key that will still be publicly visible but that's fine and it can't be avoided. **You should restrict it** to your own domain though. Follow [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key) to properly secure the key with HTTP referrer restrictions.

Also see related [What steps should I take to protect my Google Maps API Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1364858/11742502)

Hope this helps you.