# Clearing Webpack cache

Tags: angular, three.js, webpack

How do you go about forcing `webpack` to clear its cache?

I'm doing a-lot of work with `threejs` and `webpack` and for some reason, unbeknownst to me, it has two copies of `threejs` in memory. Here's the error:

[image]

This file isn't located in a hidden folder in the app folder but in webpacks memory found via the Chrome Dev tools - i.e.

[image]

So is there anyway to force webpack to clear it's cache?

Answer (score 58):

You can delete the folder "node_modules/.cache" to force Webpacker/Babel to rebuild their caches.

Comment: I had an issue with `eslint-loader` throwing errors about a previous file system state. Removing this directory seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Same as @daniels. Was getting warnings about imports that no longer existed. Deleting .cache and letting it rebuild .eslintcache seemed to sort it out.

Comment: By the way, this is *not* what `npm cache clean` removes (as I assumed)

Answer (score 10):

Webpack 5 stores the cache into `node_modules/.cache/webpack` (when using npm) or `.yarn/.cache/webpack` (when using [Yarn Plug'n'Play API](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp/)), see [Persistent Caching](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#persistent-caching).

You can deactivate the caching completely by setting `cache: false` in your [webpack config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/).

If you just want to delete your cache, then please do the following:

1. Delete `node_modules/.cache/webpack` or `.yarn/.cache/webpack`
2. Restart your webpack build (just hot reloading is not enough as files will still be cached in-memory)

When using the [webpackDevMiddleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware), then the `.cache` directory is created on your first page visit. I had to restart my dev server after deleting `.cache` to see the effects of changed files within my "node_modules" directory.

Answer (score 6):

In case this helps anyone else, I had a similar case and the issue was that in one of the files my import statement had an uppercase in the name. For example, I had

```
import {Person} from './model/Model';
```

Note that I had deleted the file ./model/Model.js but was still getting the error due to the import. Just change the import to be

```
import {Person} from './model/model';
```

and all is well again.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem, except webpack was caching a CSS file. My angular workspace doesn't have a `node_modules/.cache` folder, but I deleted the `.angular/cache` folder and that solved my problem. I also had to stop and restart the `ng serve` command after deleting that folder

Answer (score 2):

You can set `cache: false` in webpack config. This worked for me on Next.js.

Answer (score 2):

```
ng cache clean
```

Based on [the documentation](https://angular.io/cli/cache#clearing-the-cache)

Answer (score 1):

As the warning says, you have two copies of `three.js` in directories which have the same effective name when you ignore capitalization: 'three' vs 'THREE' are the same.

If they are different then rename one of them.  Or, if they are the same module, give them both an identical name, in lowercase.

Comment: webpack has cache

Answer (score -2):

To force clearing cache in the browser, you could load the generated js bundle file dynamically with javascript with a query parameter in the `src` attribute, then call a function to execute other scripts when the file is loaded:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onload = function () {
        init(); // call other scripts when this file is fully loaded
    };
    script.src = 'dist/bundle.js?v='+Date.now();

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>

<script>
    function init(argument) {
        // other scripts
        console.log('dist/bundle.js is loaded from the server not from the cache')
    }
</script>
```

see: [Dynamically load JS inside JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js#answer-14521482)

Answer (score -3):

Webpack doesn't have caching but browsers have. Files produced by Webpack compilation can remain cached unless their content has changed. On the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) they explain that to solve this issue you can add [contenthash] to your output file names.

> The [contenthash] substitution will add a unique hash based on the
>   content of an asset. When the asset's content changes, [contenthash]
>   will change as well.

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

*PS: I'm using Webpack v4.30.0*

For more, checkout [Webpack's guide for caching](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/).

Comment: My [contenthash] is changing and I confirmed that BUT the browser still uses the previous [contenthash] in the browser. i.e. the browser does not reload automatically. How does the browser detect the new [contenthash] js file??