# unwanted html style tag with href that only occur on my computer even when the server is an internal server

Tags: html, security, xss

Does any one know what this is? it looks like an XSS attack but it only seems to happen on my computer and on a server that doesn't contain `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src https://www.youtube.com/">` or some other equivalent. It doesn't seem to matter if the server with the webpage is public or not because it shows up anyways. I used a virtual machine on the same computer and it doesn't appear. Can someone tell me what this is and if I should be worried about it or not? The hrefs near the bottom are what concern me the most especially the ones that have "/track/" in the URL. I've attached a picture of what I am talking about below.

(Note: the hrefs in the picture are to websites I have never seen and this seems to be caused by my own computer not the server. The style tag in the picture appears on servers that were just created and are still at default settings.)

[unwanted style tag on private server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvUcb.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the purpose of the HTML "nonce" attribute for script and style elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922784/what-s-the-purpose-of-the-html-nonce-attribute-for-script-and-style-elements)

Comment: if it wasn't for the screen shot and the meta tag I have then yes it would be, but I just want to know if this is something to do with my computer due to is not showing up on a virtual machine on the same computer. I don't even know what this is that I'm seeing.

Comment: This is related to content security policy. It is getting set from IIS HTTP response headers-> Add custom header.

Comment: yes I know this, I want to know why this is happening to an internal server and why its only occurring with one specific computer.

Comment: Because this header is added on one particular pc only.

Comment: is there a way I can remove that? because it shows up on all browsers I have. (except the tor browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the screenshot provided, it just seems to be injecting adblock css into your page markup.

Try opening these sites in a private window where you're browser plugins aren't running or a different browser. I'm assuming you have some sort of adblock plugin which is injecting styles into the page.

Comment: Its still there even when in a private window. connected to this internal server with another computer that also has adblock but it never shows. its primarily those hrefs at the bottom that concern me, even the ones with "/track/" at the end.

Comment: Looks like, it is from Kaspersky Adblock plugin in your browser. Do you have this Kaspersky Internet Security/Adblock installed? 
https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?/topic/364131-code-in-source-of-my-website-is-it-website-protection-by-kis/&tab=comments#comment-2668196