# Which HTML elements are nonceable?

Tags: html, attributes, content-security-policy, nonce

In the context of *Content Security Policies* there can be elements that are excluded from the policy, if they have the `nonce` attribute as specified in the respective policy.

Obviously this works for some HTML elements, e.g. `<script nonce="...">` and `<style nonce="..."`. For some however, it does not work, for example `<iframe nonce="..." >`.

In the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src#sources) is written the hint:

> **Note:** The CSP `nonce` source can only be apply *nonceable* elements (e.g. as the [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) element has no `nonce` attribute, there is no way to associate it with this CSP source).

**Is there a complete list of nonceable elements?**
MDN lists the `nonce` attribute for script and style tags. On the other hand the `nonce` attribute is *not* listed for the `<link>` element, but  works anyway. Are there more elements like that?

Side question: Why are `<img>` and `<iframe>` not nonceable?

Comment: Binaries are too expensive to check for nonce compliance. Also some browsers deliver a reduced-quality version of images when they detect a slow connection. Those wouldn't meet the nonce specified, obviously.

Comment: According to [**This Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922784/what-s-the-purpose-of-the-html-nonce-attribute-for-script-and-style-elements) it appears only `Script`/`Style` elements are nonceable, and with the number of viewers and upvotes on this question I would hope that if it wasn't true someone would have noticed and commented by now.....

Comment: The CSP spec requires UAs to check nonces only for `script` & `style` elements. In the algorithm at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#match-element-to-source-list, see step 2: *If type is "script" or "style", and § 6.6.3.1 Is element nonceable? returns "Nonceable"…* And at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#is-element-nonceable, the *Is element nonceable?* algorithm itself doesn’t check just for `script` & `style` elements — but currently the spec only calls that algorithm for  `script` & `style` elements. So if you put a nonce on any other element, the spec requires browsers to ignore it

Answer (score 2):

> In the MDN Documentation is written the hint:
>
> > ```
> > Note: The CSP nonce source can only be apply nonceable elements (e.g. as the <img>
> > ```

Yeah, and in the same time Firefox v52.9 release 25/06/2018 supports nonces for `<img>`, `<iframe>`, `<object >`, `<embed>`, `<audio>` and `<video>`. If you have WinXP PC you can [ensure that](https://csplite.com/csp/test187/#test).

As the test above shows, at the moment only `<style>` and `<script>` are nonceables, even though CSP3 does not restrict the use of nonces for any HTML elements.