# How can I print the JavaScript source code in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to extract JavaScript source code in a website such as
https://stackoverflow.com/

- First method, I tried [`document.scripts`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ktnm.png) DOM API function. I got an array of HTMLElement Object. I also tried `document.scripts[0].text`, but it can not be printed.
- Second method, I used Sources panel in of Chrome DevTools [image]. But this method can not extract JS source code automatically.
- Third method, building a web **scraper** to extract `<script>` tag in website. However, this method can not extract the dynamic JS source code which can include by [jquery load script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js), for example.

So, Are there any method to extract JavaScript source code in a website?

Comment: Do you have permission to use their source code? if so then just ask them for it, otherwise you're probably breaking all sorts of copyright and legal rules

Comment: did you try some kind of plugin like the following: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin

Comment: _“I also tried document.scripts[0].text, but it can not be printed.”_ – that will of course only work for script elements that have script code embedded between the opening and closing script tag. If the script was embedded via the `src` attribute of the script element however, you would need to look at that.

Comment: @CBroe ...via the `src` attribute

Comment: @CBroe If we can take advantage of the source code in Source panel is better since it already downloaded in browser.

Comment: That source panel is part of dev tools. That is nothing you can easily hook into with JS that runs in the context of a website. "Save page as ..." could perhaps be a possibility, have you tried that? That at least stores all the external script files (together with the rest of the page assets.)