# How can I manually initialize an angular 2/4 app

Tags: angular

I need to initialize an angular app with the component my-app,
the problem is that this component exists on a html template that is not loaded on page start so I have to manually initialize, otherwise it gives me an error showing this message:
Error: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

Is that possible?

Comment: You may want to stick with the normal process of using App module and App component as your startup process. Have you tried using the Angular CLI to generate that boilerplate code for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SystemJS you can create the element dynamically using `document.createElement()` and append using `appendChild()` then call `System.import()` to initialize the app. This assumes that all necessary application assets and SystemJS configuration has been loaded already:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <button type="button" id="foo">Click Me</button>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('foo');
  var container = document.getElementById('app');

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var myApp = document.createElement('my-app');
    myApp.textContent = 'Loading...';

    container.appendChild(myApp);

    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  });
})();
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gkXxL2Rc6qIkXal8x8l5?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality. The app element is created, appended, and initialized from within the event handler of the button click.

**UPDATE** If you're using Webpack and depending on your build/bundling process, you can load the main transpiled/bundle JS file dynamically using a pattern in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js) to avoid your error. If you're using `@angular/cli` this may be more difficult as generated files have identifiers such as `main.97e5159ded9c783f627a.bundle.js`.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that. First create a root app module and declare your root component in `declarations` and `entryComponents`. **Do not** add it to `bootstrap` components. Then define `ngDoBootstrap` method on the module class to let Angular know you will be bootstrapping the application yourself. Inside this method obtain the reference to the `ApplicationRef` and then when the time comes simply call `bootstrap` on it passing the `AppComponent` class reference. Here is the code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap(app: ApplicationRef) {
    // delay bootstrap by 3 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      app.bootstrap(AppComponent)
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Essentially this is what Angular does under the hood when you call `bootstrapModule(AppModule);` with `boostrapComponents` specified.

Read [How to manually bootstrap an Angular application](https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-to-manually-bootstrap-an-angular-application-9a36ccf86429) for more details.