# Substitute JQuery min for normal files for debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to somehow substitute jquery.min.js for a version with more descriptive function and variable names when I'm debugging? I'm very lost when debugging a JavaScript app and I believe that an insight into what the JQuery does could be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: *is it possible?* **Yes**. Alternatively, you can also use a *sourceMap* file. But for proper solution, please share how are you getting `jQuery`. Is it from `npm` or `cdn` or a local file?

Comment: Do you mean a non-minified version of jQeury. If so you can just download this from the official website.

Comment: Generally, where you have (eg) `../jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js` change it to `../jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js` (ie simply remove `.min`)

Comment: If you're debugging someone else's site, then you can try what's suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521482/2181514  to load un-min'd version of jquery over the top - but it likely breaks any 3rd-party scripts.

Comment: Alternatively, use a proxy (fiddler?) to load the un-min'd version when the min'd version is requested by your browser.

Answer (score -1):

You can download the uncompressed and well-commented jQuery code [here.](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js)

Or if you are using a CDN for your project you could use the uncompressed version of the Google hosted jQuery CDN like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: **Don't just downvote unless there is a reason for it,** @Dominik asked for a more descriptive version of jQuery and this is what I shared. **CHANGE YOUR ATTITUDE**