# How do I call Scripts.Render inside of a javascript blog in MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am adding SystemJS to my project but I still need to make use of some of the bundles I've defined in BundleConfig.cs. I want to import dependencies using SystemJS, but I can't render my own code until those dependencies are loaded.

Here's my cshtml file

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>My-App</title>

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/base") // SystemJS and polyfills

</head>

<body>
    <script>
       System.import("angular")
        .then(function () {

             // THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO RENDER ANOTHER BUNDLE

          })
    </script>
<body>
</html>
```

Just shoving `@Scripts.Render` into the script block breaks the HTML script parsing -- because all that does is inject a bunch of script tags.

Please note that I am specifically looking for MVC cshtml solutions that will allow me to call my pre-defined bundles -- I'm hoping to avoid manually writing script imports for every file in my project.

Comment: related, though this specifically has to do with MVC script bundles

Comment: no, it injects a separate script tag for every file in the bundle

Comment: at least for debug

Comment: only for debug version, there are multiple files

Comment: You can use webessentials to create a static bundled file and load it here.

Comment: okay, yes, I can make it bundle by default and then use the jquery.getScript from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to load scripts dynamically inside your JavaScript, you're going to have to just have hard-coded path references. You can't use something like `Scripts.Render`, as you figured out.

However, this isn't really an issue if you understand how the bundling system works. The bundle you create, i.e. `~/bundles/base`, is *actually* a route to that bundle. In other words, you can literally do something like:

```
 <script src="/bundles/base"></script>
```

And that bundled JavaScript will be included. So just use that route with your script loader.

Comment: thank you! that's what I ended up doing actually -- using System.import no less

Comment: In my BundleConfig.cs I did this: "BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;" Because I don't want my files minified/bundled on my local test environment. When doing your solution it gets bundled anyway. Is there a way to retrieve the list of paths/files in a bundle as an array?