# Trying to load A js link after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a js link after 5 second page load . when my page load then js link work.

My link is

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

when page is load then after 5 second this link will be work.

Comment: Had you tried something ?

Comment: why and what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a script element in the DOM. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521482/8750116).

Waht you can do is insert the script element with a setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = function () {
        //do stuff when the script is loaded
    };
    script.src = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script); //or something of the likes
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this using `promises`:

```
// Make a function to return a promise for the sleep duration
function sleep(ms)
{
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// make a function to handle the sleep
async function loadNewScript(seconds, src)
{
    await sleep(seconds * 1000);   // This is 5 seconds (time in miliseconds)
    getScript(src);   
}

// make a function to get the script
function getScript(src)
{
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
    {
        var s;
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = src;
        s.onload = resolve;
        s.onerror = reject;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
    });
}

// And then just call it on pageload (this is not full page load, only DOM)
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
   // loadNewScript(seconds, src)
   loadNewScript(5, "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `defer` option in your script tag.

```
<script defer src="..."></script>
```

With this option the script downloading/execution won't interfere with the html parsing.

[Here](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.) you can see another options.