# Ensure load of javascript before proceed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following js includes:

```
<script src="~/js/api/config.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/authentication.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/es6-promise-polyfill/promise.min.js"></script>
<script>Vue.use(VeeValidate)</script>
<script src="~/js/home.js"></script>
```

`authentication.js` has an ajax call. `home.js` must not be called before authentication and its `ajax` calls has completed. Is this possible?

Comment: load home.js in callback/promise complete of that ajax call?

Comment: check this answer out for dynamically loading js script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the following function from `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` event

```
function loadJS() {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = '/js/home.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```