# Create and Load JS file from JS code string returned from AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to dynamically load html content and execute JS on ajax response. The response object has two *key:value pairs*.

- `content`: having the html elements
- `js`: having the required js

Here's the code:

```
$.post("/some_url.php",{job: "getThatPage"},function(response) {

    /* parsing response as JSON */
    let ajaxResponse = JSON.parse(response);

    /* adding content to page body */
    $("body").html(ajaxResponse.content);

    /* now ajax.js is a string containing the required JS*/
    /* how to execute this script? */

});
```

Script returned from an ajax request doesn't get executed even If its added to the DOM, thats why I have separated the content and script. I know I can put the required JS into a separate file and load it with `getScript()` on success but that wont help me here because my **ajax request is returning some customised JS for every logged in user.**

I think it can be solved if somehow I was able to create a `.js file` and put the contents of `ajax.js` into it and load it using `getScript()` method. That's what my silly mind tells me.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js)
Surely you saw it by now :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the content contains a script tag? If not wrap it in one.

```
$('body').append ($('<script>').html(ajaxResponse.content));
```

Comment: Content doesn't contain any script tags. thanks a ton, learned something new today. BTW its `ajaxResponse.js` instead of `ajaxResponse.content`.