# Import JS library dynamically at runtime in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I'm using `Angular 6`.

I'm writing an application using `canvas` and there are plenty of 
 prebuilt `templates` to use with the canvas.

The source file is saved in a `.js` file on the server which is retrieved when the user selects a particular template and canvas is to be rendered again with the new template.

Not much has been done in the `component` file, still, my `component` file contains

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'fabric';

declare const fabric: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-fb-ad-modal',
  templateUrl: './create-fb-ad-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-fb-ad-modal.component.css']
})
export class CreateFbAdModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product;

  canvasTemplatePath = 'https://example.com/template01.js';

  canvas: any;

  textString: string;
  backgroundImagePath = 'https://example.com/assets/bg/3.png';
  productImagePath: string;

  constructor(
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    /**
     * Set variables
     */
    this.textString = this.product.info.title;
    this.productImagePath = this.product.info.images.main;

  }

  private _initializeCanvasTemplate()
  {
    // load canvasTemplatePath here and call the function inside the loaded
    // file with parameters
    // For example:
    // importedTemplate.renderCanvas(this.canvas, this.backgroundImagePath, this.productImagePath, this.textString);
    // this will render the canvas according to the content of template01.js
  }
}
```

**component.html** contains

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="628"></canvas>
```

and the `template01.js` file contains

```
function renderCanvas(canvas, bgImage, pImage, text)
{
    const cvBgImage = new fabric.Image.fromURL(bgImage, imgInstance => {
      imgInstance.set({
        width: canvas.width,
        height: canvas.height,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top'
      });
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(imgInstance, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
   });

   canvas.on('mouse:down', options => {
     canvas.setActiveObject(this.cvTextString);
     cvTextString.bringToFront();
   });

   const cvTextString = new fabric.IText(text, {
     left: 100,
     top: 220,
     fontSize: 32,
   });
   canvas.add(cvTextString);
   canvas.setActiveObject(cvTextString);

   const cvProductImage = new fabric.Image.fromURL(pImage, imgInstance => {
     imgInstance.set({
       left: 800,
       top: 120
     });

     canvas.add(imgInstance);
   });

}
```

Now I want to load the `template01.js` file and call the function inside it `renderCanvas()` by passing values from the component which will render the canvas accordingly.

**But, How to import/load the external js from URL at runtime as there will be more than 400 template files.**

I'm not sure whether I'm doing it correctly or not as I'm learning `Angular` and this is my first Angular project.

Comment: it's pretty easy to load additional js files into your document, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js

Comment: Those examples are for normal javascript. How can I do this in Angular? Angular build the scripts before loading in the browser and served from `dist` directory.

Comment: you can do this from inside a component of your, 'document' is available there. You can move your .js file to your assets folder and load them from there... after a script has loaded, the "renderCanvas" function will be available in the global namespace, so you can call this method also from anywhere in your angular code...

Answer (score 0):

Your `template01.js` script file change to exporting type.  for ex:

```
export class renderClass {
   function renderCanvas(canvas, bgImage, pImage, text) {
       //.. Your script file renderCanvas method codes.
   }
}
```

Next your component file top import that script file method. for ex:

```
import { renderClass } from './template01.js'; // (correct location of your script file)
```

Next add that method in constructor. for ex:

```
constructor(private renderClass: renderClass) {}
```

next call that method

```
private _initializeCanvasTemplate() {
   this.renderClass.renderCanvas(canvas, bgImage, pImage, text);
}
```

Comment: But the `template01.js` file will change dynamically. There will be multiple `template files` like `template01.js`, `template02.js`, so on. And I have to import only one at a time.

Comment: use multiple function in renderClass class

Comment: can't use multiple functions inside `renderClass` because I have been given files in a zip. Now I will have to write 400 functions one by one for 400 files to do as your suggestion.