# after AJAX content loads multiple scrips need to reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an website where the menu runs with AJAX for an smooth page transition but i am running into the problem of having to reload my page after my AJAX because on the loaded content the does not get effected by the Javascript files.

```js
$.ajax({
  history.pushState(url, null, url_i_am_requesting);
  url: url_i_am_requesting,
  success: function(html) {
    var content = $('<div />').html(html).find('.page-wrapper');
    $('.page-wrapper').html(content);
  }
});
```

I have found that  `jQuery.getScript()` works fine, but when I have around 10 Javascript files, is there a way to execute them all again after the AJAX has finished without calling them one by one?

Comment: The JS code you've shown is invalid; you can't randomly set `pushState` in the middle of the object you provide to `$.ajax`. Regarding the issue, it simply sounds like you need to use delegated event handlers for the content you inject in to `.page-wrapper`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521217/3481654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `$.getScript()` is buggy sometimes, so I use my own implementation of it like:

```
jQuery.loadScript = function (url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: callback,
        async: true
    });
}
```

and use it like:

```
if (typeof someObject == 'undefined') $.loadScript('url_to_someScript.js', function(){
    //Stuff to do after someScript has loaded
});
```