# load jquery plugin file after jQuery deffered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a js file which I want to load after Jquery deffered function. 
Thing is that I am bring data in my **getData** function and then inject string into the DOM. After that js file will initialize that code. That is the reason I want to call js file after my code runs

How can I do that

Below is my code.

> jQuery function decalaration

```
function getData(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose',
    },
  })
}
```

> function call

```
getData(url).then(function(data){

});
```

Now I want to call jQuery file after **finish of then** function.

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you looking to do that?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Good question. Thing is that I am bring data in my **getData** function and then loading. So js will initialize that code. That is the reason to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically load JS inside JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Promise/await way, Since you need to write js file after execute something, so that you can let js file wait until your code finished, and then write your new js file to body....check this example:

```
/* MEthod used to write js to body script */
function addJsFileToBody(jsSrc)
{
    var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = jsSrc;
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
}

var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose',
    },
    complete: function(data) {
      resolve(data);
    }
  })
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  addJsFileToBody('file.js');
});
```

Reference and example: 
[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)