# How to load a Javascript Library via a URL in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I sometimes need to load my JS libraries like this so I always get the current version...

```
<script src="https://cdn.domain.com/file.js"></script>
```

However, my current issue, is I need to load this file in my Javascript code, not through HTML.

PseudoCode:

```
waitforload(getscript('https://cdn.domain.com/file.js'));
```

I need to load the file and then wait until loaded to proceed on to additional code that uses the library (file.js)

What is the best way to do this? I can't seem to find a simple and good solution.

#### Not a duplicate

As both solutions recommends using callbacks. I do not want to use a callback to execute code after it's run. I want the library to load, then move on to the next code to execute.

[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

[Dynamically load JS inside JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js)

Example:

```
 waitforload(getscript('https://cdn.domain.com/file.js'));

 el = new Helpers.Domain.fromFileJs();
 el.something();
```

Vs.

```
 waitforload(getscript('https://cdn.domain.com/file.js', 'mycode()'));

function my code()
  el = new Helpers.Domain.fromFileJs();
  el.something();
end
```

As to me, the first version easier to deal with as I am loading a module full of helpers classes and other code, and it's not just one item.

Comment: _"As both solutions recommends using callbacks. I do not want to use a callback to execute code after it's run. I want the library to load, then move on to the next code to execute."_ What do you think a callback does?

Comment: It's the implementation. In one, I have to do: some function(callback);, the other, I run code on one line, then run code on next line. I don't need to wait for a response, just that it loads.

Comment: call your external library in the head tag and call the other js file at the bottom just before the closing body tag

Comment: I am testing in Teaspoon-Jasmine, can't do that. It does not work.