# Load external JS without impact TTI

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have multiple external js from the same provider that I insert into the website to embed Instagram (it created galleries for each insert). Unfortunately, this JS negatively impacts Google page speed significantly. I am talking about a reduction in 20 - 23 points on mobile and desktop.

Unfortunately, this product doesn't have any other option to embed. It is a normal  tag. I have tried async and defer, but no use as google is clever and considers all the scripts on the page to be loaded to calculate  Time to Interactive, which is delayed. Obviously the SEO is taking a hit as the website performance is getting a hit.

The question, is there a way I can load all these scripts without influencing the DCL (DomContentLoaded) and TTI? Any help is appreciated. It is sufficient that these scripts are loaded when the DOM element is in view.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't split them up to several chunks, I would suggest you load these files on dynamically on demand (when they're needed).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521482/1860540) shows how to load a script dynamically.