# Use an online script/cdn package without any html

Tags: javascript, node.js, plotly, discord, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot using discord.js so I don't use any HTML in my project. I wanted to use plotly.js but the npm package seems to be greatly outdated (last update late 2015) while the CDN link is kept updated. Is there a way to load it and use that instead? How could I get the same result that `<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>` would give me but in plain JS?

Comment: In my experience with CDN packages, getting the link directly from cdnjs.com and using that link as the src usually works for me. This is the link I found when searching for "plotly" at cdnjs.com: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plotly.js/1.51.1/plotly.min.js

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically load JS inside JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js)

Answer (score 0):

I think you viewed the wrong package.

When checking out [plotly.js/master/package.json](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/package.json), we can see that the name of the package is `plotly.js`, wich is found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotly.js.

To install use `npm i plotly.js`.

Alternative you can insall directly from the master branch with `npm i plotly/plotly.js`.

Comment: I just noticed this but gives me a ``var style = document.getElementById(id);`` error I'm assuming because I have no HTML in my project. Any workarounds?

Comment: It looks like plotly _was_ the correct package because it works on node https://github.com/plotly/plotly-nodejs#plotlygetimagefigure-options-callback
so guess this cant be fixed :/

Comment: What about `npm i plotly/plotly-nodejs`

Comment: https://github.com/plotly/plotly-nodejs the repo hasn't really been updated for 4 years, that's what I'm using.