# Lazy Loading external javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript that's load iframe on the website. i want to lazy load that script. i tried `async` or `defer` and loading dynamically but it doesn't load iframe. is there any way to load this script lazy or after a few seconds.

```
<div class="editorskit-no-mobile">
<script src="//idx.diversesolutions.com/scripts/controls/Remote-Frame.aspx?MasterAccountID=1606&amp;SearchSetupID=41&amp;LinkID=474907&amp;Height=2000"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically load JS inside JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js)

Comment: why don't you simply create the script and attach after some seconds?

Comment: @emix No. you can try on jsfiddle.

Comment: it doesn't even with defer and async https://jsfiddle.net/uzairm/zc5ge27v/

Comment: It won't work because the remote script sucks.

Answer (score 0):

a very simple solution from your code, leave the `<div>` without content

```html
<div class="editorskit-no-mobile"></div>
```

and then, a simple `createElement` and `appendChild`

```js
<script>
  var divElm = document.querySelector('.editorskit-no-mobile')
  setTimeout(function() {
    appendScript(divElm)
  }, 2000) // 2 seconds

  var appendScript = function(elm) {
    var s = document.createElement('script')
    s.src = '//idx.diversesolutions.com/scripts/controls/Remote-Frame.aspx?MasterAccountID=1606&amp;SearchSetupID=41&amp;LinkID=474907&amp;Height=2000'
    s.type = 'text/javascript'
    s.async = !0
    elm.appendChild(s)
  }
</script>
```

this way, you are creating the `<script>` tag on the fly, without loading anything until it actually appends it into the DOM...

Comment: didn't work. it doesn't load the iframe. https://jsfiddle.net/uzairm/zc5ge27v/

Comment: when I tried, didn't work and I got warnings about cross-site cookies, so I only assumed it was dependable on the domain it was called because if you open the script URL in an anonymous page, you see it actually writes nothing at all...