# Load JavaScript from HTML text dynamically?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, single-page-application

I have a modular single page html that dynamically loads content html based on a wide variety of attributes which are not important. The code below works great except the script is not loaded. I have a place in the dynamic load function to insert script but can't find any examples of this type of loading. Everything assumes an src file however I know you can do something like below with element.text but not sure how to load that from the html text.

Note that all the references I have found load via an .src and not the .text which I need.

```
function dynamicLoad(elem, sourceCode) {
        // load html not the issue        
        elem.innerHTML = sourceCode;
        // load JS -- this is with solution ---
        var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(); // Sandbox
        doc.body.innerHTML = sourceCode; // Parse HTML properly
 // --- This is the solution below, will load all scripts found    
        [].map.call(doc.getElementsByTagName('script'), function(el) {       
          var e = document.createElement('script');
          e.text = el.textContent;
          document.body.appendChild(e);        
        }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js

Comment: Do you want to execute the loaded script tag? then you could use the `eval` function to execute the javascript inside

Comment: @AdnaneAr will that load the script?
Using the above code, would that be eval(data) ?
This gives an error "VM: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

Comment: You can try to get the js script as string and execute it like that `eval(jsString)`

Comment: Why exactly are you using javascript,  to create a script tag, that will contain static text that you then immediately append with the intent to execute as javascript? isn't that just a roundabout way of... just executing some javascript? If you're gonna fetch the script's content... you mightaswell just append a script element with a src.

Comment: @KevinB this is part of a very large enterprise dynamic application where different html and scripts need to be loaded based on attributes as I explained above. Customer A gets one script while customer B gets different html/js. Think of it as a CMS in the browser wo the CMS. Pure HTML/JS no external dependencies.

Comment: if.. you're fetching it, that's a dependency is it not?

Comment: It is not as this is a function included in modern browsers. Your nitpicking on the why not the how. Problem solution is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to my comment over this answer, I don't know if that is actually what you are looking for but I hope it will help!

```js
var loadedScript = "alert('Eval is working!')";

function evalScript() {
  return eval(loadedScript);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="evalScript()">Eval script</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is posted inline code above but here it is:

```
// Insert JS 
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(); // Sandbox
doc.body.innerHTML = data; // Parse HTML properly
[].map.call(doc.getElementsByTagName('script'), function(el) {       
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.text = el.textContent;
  document.body.appendChild(e);        
});
```