# How do I get a dropdown list to load a js file?

Tags: javascript, html

Creating a quiz and I want to load a js file based on the selection from a dropdown box, so far I have the following to assign the class as the category-name:

```
    <div>
      <label for="test">Select test:</label>
      <select id="test" class="category-name" name="test">
        <option value="a.js">A</option>
        <option value="b.js">B</option>
        <option value="c.js">C</option>
       </select>
    </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary lift" onclick="loadQuestionsForCategory()">Load Questions</button>      
    </section>

    <script src='assets/resources/questions.js'></script>
```

Instead of loading questions.js, how would I load a.js or b.js depending on the option that's selected?

Answer (score 0):

use onChange function

```
<select id="test" class="category-name"  name="test">
   <option value="a.js">A</option>
   <option value="b.js">B</option>
   <option value="c.js">C</option>
</select>

//if js
function loadQuestionsForCategory(){
   var page = document.getElementById('test').value;
   window.location = page;
}
```

if your looking for only script loading check this out [Dynamically load JS inside JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js)