# Load an external JS file on a page **after** wherever jQuery is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load an external JS file on a page **after** wherever jQuery is loaded.

The solution below doesn't seem to work that way as I don't just want to load an external file rather after wherever jquery < script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js">  is loaded:

```
$("main").append($("<script></script>").attr("src", url));
```

Any thoughts are highly appreciated.

Comment: javascript is evaluated from top to bottom, so it should be enough to use the <script> including jquery before anything else.

Comment: or you could follow the answer here that perfectly fits your exact scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js

Comment: you are probably aiming at the wrong solution to address a problem you are having that you didn't state in your question. Something like trying to attach an event handler to a dom element without the page being loaded yet.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita - think you are right. I only want an external file/script loaded after jquery or appended after jquery is loaded. Not sure which would make sense but that's what I need to do.

Comment: just have the script tag for your JS file after the script tag of jquery?

Comment: @AsifRaza then you have your solution and I don't know why you are still trying to explicitely load a js after jQuery. You've already got your answer if you have nothing else to add to the question. jQuery will be loaded before anything else if it appears as the first <script> tag in the page. The link I shared shows exactly how to load a js on demand if that's really required (and it isn't in your case unless you really want to for some educational purpose).