# How can I call a library script after page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, locomotive-scroll, locomotivejs

I'm trying to call a library script (locomotive) in vanilla JS without Jquery, after the whole page and its assets had loaded. I've already tried with something like this:

```
<body onload="script('./js/lib/locomotive.min.js')";>
```

But it isn't working, the whole page loads but the script is never called. I've also tried placing the **defer** after the scripts call, but still nothing. I saw this other solution in other comments:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    //....
    //  **But I don't know how to call in here the 
      *./js/lib/locomotive.min.js*** 

});
```

Is there something else I could try?

Comment: You could dynamically load the file on the `DOMContentLoaded` event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js

Answer (score 0):

Your answer may be how to dynamic import script in js.
the base way is that insert a  tag by dom api.

e.g.

```
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = './js/lib/locomotive.min.js'
document.head.appendChild(script)
```

if you wanna more functions, plz try [loadjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadjs)