# Import javascript in browser console (moodle)

Tags: javascript, moodle

I'm trying to import js code into the browser console and I'm not being able to. I've tried 'src', 'innerHTML', etc.
Is there a way to make it work?

I have also tried uploading the file 'jszip.min.js' to the website and trying to import from there, but neither...

Left a sample code:

```js
var jsZipScript = document.createElement("script");
jsZipScript.type = "text/javascript";
jsZipScript.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.5.0/jszip.min.js";
jsZipScript.onload = function () {
  jsZipLoaded();
};
document.head.appendChild(jsZipScript);

function jsZipLoaded() {
  console.log("LOAD");
  
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (window.JSZip) {
      console.log("OK");
    } else {
      console.log("window.JSZip no está presente.");
    }
    
    try {
      var zip = new JSZip();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("JSZip no está definido.");
    }
  }, 6000);
}
```

And yes, if I try the typical `jsZipScript.innerHTML="alert('...')"` it works

**I give context:**

I want to download some files together in a zip and I can't touch the code of the website where the files are **(it's a Moodle)**. I've thought about using the `jszip` library for this.

So, I go to the website, press `F12` to open the console and paste the code. It does not work:

```js
LOAD
window.JSZip is not present
JSZip is not defined
```

What seems strange to me is that on other websites, it does work

**If anyone can think of another way to download several files in an orderly manner (folders or something like that), please comment.**

Comment: I don't understand the goal here, what do you mean by "import js code into the browser console"?

Comment: It looks like the given code is trying to dynamically load some external JavaScript. Are you having issues with this code? Or are you trying to load the given code itself?

Comment: for all modern browsers you can remove the `jsZipScript.type = "text/javascript";` line as they all default to that now for script elements

Comment: Uhm im not sure, but this seems to be working in the fiddle you posted, it logs OK. Are you  might having any other configuration issues?

Comment: Feels like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14521108/125981 without more information here

Answer (score 0):

> If anyone can think of another way to download several files in an orderly manner (folders or something like that), please comment.

What files are you trying to download? An activity?

Do you have an admin account?

Comment: It is a folder with files. And in the non-editing view, it does not have a download all button. If there are 300 files you have to download one by one. There is also a section where Moodle generates files and shows them in a unitary way.

Comment: Again, what files are they? Which activity?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was another question.  Most are pdf, there is also word, rtf, etc.  Above all, it is the “personalized certificate” activity.

Comment: There isn't a "personalized certificate" activity that I know of, is it one of these? https://moodle.org/plugins/?q=certificate%20category:1 - also can I ask why you want to download all the certificates? Are you trying to scrape the site?