# Relaoding Div with Shortcodes in WORDPRESS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using jQuery load(); to reload a div on event. The reloaded div contains shortcodes processing POST data.

The load(); method is not executing shortcodes when reloading, how can I process my shortcodes when reloading a div in WordPress?

```
function RGeneral(){
    locGen=window.location.href + " #Edit_General";
    (jQuery).ready(   
                   (jQuery)('#Edit_General').load(locGen)
                   )}
```

Currently, the div "#Edit_General" reloads with empty shortcodes when the function "RGeneral( )" is called.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post all of the functions related to this question?

Comment: [How to load script with jquery.load()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5519840/16125139)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @HowardE , That's all I'm working with. Basically I am running this function on an onclick="" HTML tag. It currently works but doesn't reprocess shortcodes, instead an empty shortcode is returned